# String saved in IOS app, accessible from web browser. Best method?

Tags: ios, string, core-data

As the title says, I'm looking for a string to be input in an IOS app and stored in a way that it would be accessible from a web browser.

Both editable and readable from web and the app.

From initial googling, I've come across Dropbox Datastore API but it is being deprecated.

What would be a good alternative for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intentions are quite scant.  However, I assume you want a little more than just reading and writing a string.  Inferring a bit more context, you should look at [Apple's CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/).

It has API for iOS, OS X, and apparently now javascript.  See this link for more details.

Comment: Sorry yeah my description was a bit all over the place. Basically a note taking app with the notes being accessed from a website / web browser. Would CloudKit cover this? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that.  Follow that link and watch the 2015 WWDC video presentation.  It should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You need some code running on a server and a database to save the string, with an API to access this string from a client.

[FireBase](https://www.firebase.com) is probably the simplest drop in solution since it gives you a very basic example and a web based UI for testing (plus it updates in realtime)